# I'm not getting badge/privilege notifications any more

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

In the last week or two I've noticed, on more than one SE site, that I'm no longer getting those banner notices for newly-earned badges or privileges.  I've seen this on both Firefox 12.0 on OS 10.6 and Firefox 3.6 on Windows XP.  It is possible that this is due to some plugin or browser update suddenly deciding that those are no good, but I haven't installed any *new* plugins lately nor made any more restrictive.  (Also, that ancient FF version on XP is a work machine and browser updates are disabled, though plugins update.)  I run with NoScript (my SE sites are white-listed), AdBlock Plus, and several that should be irrelevant.

Is anybody else seeing this -- or *not* seeing it, i.e. you're seeing these notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per a recent [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/):

> Notifications are now…
>
> - a tab in the Stack Exchange Genuine dropdown
> - global: get a badge on Stack Overflow and you’ll see the notice on Gaming
> - dismissed with one click, just like the inbox
> - available historically: the last 45 are available, rather than disappearing forever once read

That means (unfortunately), no more Big Slidy Orange<sup>TM</sup> bars.

Comment: Thanks!  Bummer, since it's not obvious that the dropdown has updated.  (If you have *any* replies it's already lit up, and clearing those replies on individual sites doesn't clear them there.)  For badges there's a visual hint if you're paying attention (a number changed), but for privs there's nothing.